# didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo not getting called if creating a Cocoa Touch Framework in SWIFT3

Tags: swift3, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to create a Cocoa Touch Framework for media needs.
while using my framework, to get a photo from Photo Library, the callback is not getting fired.
Following is a snippet of myframework code:

```
public func importFromGallery (viewCtrl: UIViewController, resultCallback: @escaping (_ image: UIImage, _ error: Int) -> Void) {
    let imageController = UIImagePickerController()
    imageController.delegate = self
    imageController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary
    viewCtrl.present(imageController, animated: true, completion: {
        () in
        print("viewCtrl.present completion") // Can see this in console
    })
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    print("didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo") // Can't see this!
}
```

is not getting a called without any error or warning.
However, the same code works if I try to use directly in a single view application.

xcode project for Consumer App(14PhotoGallery) & Framework (MyMediaLib) (82KB total): https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/82695417/Stackoverflow/Media_PoC.zip

Comment: try declaring `let imageController = UIImagePickerController()` out of your importFromGallery method

Comment: Hi @LeoDabus. Tried that but still not working. Any other suggestions??